# Getting this ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined on postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

maybe someone can help me, I'm stucked and can't find the issue with simple task -
I need to add id to the collectionvariables, and usually I used this command

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("board_id", jsonData.id);
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ReferenceError:
> jsonData is not defined

Maybe someone can tell me direction to look on? Tried on different tasks, and on other projects it works without any problems.

Comment: What is `jsonData` here? it should be defined before you set the collection variable like
`var jsonData= pm.response.json();` and then `pm.collectionVariables.set("board_id", jsonData.id);`

Comment: My guess is that "jsonData" is assigned to the response of an API call (or a particular part of a response), and that the API call did not execute properly so there was no response, or it did execute but the response was not as expected. It is impossible to tell based on the information you have given us